# Geometric Measure Theory prerequisites

Tags: advice, geometric-measure-theory

What are topics good to familiarize oneself with, if one wants to study geometric measure theory?

I've learned exterior algebra (Grassmann algebra), and I want to know if I should seek anything next, or just jump into textbooks on Geometric Measure Theory. Maybe differential geometry?

Comment: Umm ... you know some measure theory, right?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: It might depend on the course, but you might need to know measure theory up to general integration, the fundational topics of functional analysis (dual of Banach spaces), weak derivatives and Sobolev spaces.

Comment: @Gae.S.it's not for a course, I'm learning by myself

Comment: [This search](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-measure-theory%20reference-request?) might turn up something useful.

Comment: @Jakobian You might want to look directly at what the textbook indicates as prerequisites, then. Perhaps consult one from your local library.

Comment: If I wanted to learn weak derivatives and Sobolev spaces, where should I look for them? @Gae.S.

Comment: @Jakobian Brézis' *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations* should cover them, but any textbook for a graduate course in functional analysis should have those.

Comment: *If I wanted to learn weak derivatives and Sobolev spaces* --- Maybe [**Weakly Differentiable Functions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387970177) by William P. Ziemer, if you have the background (see its table of contents). [review by David Preiss](https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/23/3/314/349167)

Comment: Dive right into any geometric measure theory book! Morgan's or Krantz' are easy to digest.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the classical book of Federer (Herbert Federer. Geometric measure theory. 1969). It has the opinion of being hard to digest but I believe it is a matter of methodology (and taste). It is also really self-contained so you do not need know much beforehand (apart from some point-set topology). My advice is the following:

1. read from the first chapter without omitting anything and make notes;
2. be prepared to invest 2-3 working months (not doing anything else) to get acquainted with the topic;
3. teach someone what you have learned.

I think it is not really possible to "jump into" the topic.